# Android - screen orientation landscape (fragment)

Tags: android, fragment, landscape-portrait, screen-rotation

i have a fragment that i need to display it in portrait and in landscape mode, the problem is that when i rotate the device when the fragment is already showing it's not take the right dimens (pic 1), only when i open the fragment and i already in landscape mode it's taken the right dimensions (pic 2).
[image: pic 1:]

[image: pic 2:]

Comment: have you created both landscape and portrait layouts?

Comment: no, i use values-land and values-port and it's work fine except this bug

Comment: Is there any Java code involve in this resizing or this is purely XML?

Comment: no, there is no java code involved